# how to convert a string to a float? (temperature converter)

Tags: python-3.x

i have an exercise that asks me to build a temperature converter.
i need to ask a user what temperature he needs to convert then by the last letter c or f i will convert the temperature.

we didnt learn yet how to use def: , i was asked to use only if and elif statements.
this is one of the things i tried but nothing seems to work for me:

```py
temp = (input('enter a temperature you would like to convert: ')

if temp[-1] == 'c':
    print(float(temp -32)/ 1.8) + 'f'
elif temp[-1] == 'f':
    print(float(temp * 1.8) + 32) + 'c'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a string to a float or int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)

Comment: The problem is with your equation implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
temp = input('enter a temperature you would like to convert: ')

if temp[-1] == 'c':
    print(str((float(temp[:-1]) * (9/5)) + 32) + 'f')
elif temp[-1] == 'f':
    print(str((float(temp[:-1]) + 32) * (5/9) ) + 'c')
```

The conversion formulas you used are not correct. here are the correct ones:

Input 11

- F to C: `(11°F − 32) × 5/9 = -11.67°C`
- C to F: `(11°C × 9/5) + 32 = 51.8°F`

Comment: I was leaving something for them to have to do to finish their homework... :)